# Regex (VS Code) Find & Replace sub-string

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, replace

I am attempting to create a find and replace in VS Code with Regex to find strings that are inside brackets () but the opening bracket has a space before it, these strings should also contain a substring of '.md' just before the closing bracket.

The replace would be to remove the '.md' from just before the closing bracket.

E.g. **" (wordswords.md)"** would become **" (wordswords)"**

And something like **"](wordswords.md)"** would not be changed (no space before the first bracket).

I have got as far as identifying the correct bracket types with (?<=\s()
however I am unsure as to how to get the '.md' from here.

It would also work to replace the last 4 characters with a ')' instead, but I've looked and not found any methods to do so that work in VS Code.

New to Regex so any advice here or recommendations of helpful tools would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find

```
( \([^)]+)\.md\)
```

replace with

```
$1)
```

Comment: @Scipio if it answers the question you can mark it as the solution

Comment: Done that now, my b.